# Copy an existing Xcode project results in files with wrong references

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a working project that builds ok. (Xcode 6.0.1)
There were images added that were at one folder (/Downloads) and were substituted by new ones (/MyDir/MyProject). 
At adding files process copy options, group and add to it's targets were selected.
After a copy and paste at Finder from the root project folder to the new project some images contain references at Targets / Build Phases / Copy Bundle Resources to old folder (Downloads) while they are ok at original project.

I've deleted the .git from initial project to make sure it's not a git problem.
Already tried

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
```

Any ideas? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In the rightmost panel, which contains Identity and Type, check to see if the "Location" field is Absolute Path, Relative to Group, or Relative to Project, and set each file accordingly to what it should be.  Xcode seems to create new files with creative ideas on how this should be set.

Answer (score 0):

check in your project build phases if there are some missing references and delete the one you don't need
[image]

Comment: Files are all there but with a wrong folder reference. For example, in original points to /currentPicDir and in pasted version it points to /oldPicDir

Comment: then you should delete all wrong references and recreate them by clicking the + button that you can find at the bottom of the bundle resources list

Comment: Yes, of course. But the big question here is why it is happening? At first project values are ok.